# How to enable jsonp in node js http server without express api

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, node.js

I have been pulling my hairs for two days to remotely read json data from my server after which I realized that it is only possible with `jsonp` enabled.

I then dug into `jsonp` and setup my client side as follows,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$.ajax({
  //JSONP API
  url: "http://192.168.1.2:8000/temperature_now.json?callback=jsonpcallback?",
  //the name of the callback function
  jsonp: "jsonpcallback",
  //tell jQuery to expect JSONP
  dataType: "jsonp",
  //tell YQL what we want and that we want JSON
  data: {
    id: "123"
  },
  //work with the response
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data); //formatted JSON data
  }
});
</script>

<title>An JSONP example from w3resource</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

But I am not getting output.
The output should be something like,

```
{"temperature_record":[{"unix_time":1475378421086,"celsius":19.8}]}
```

However, I am getting this error in chrome console,

```
temperature_now.json?callback=jsonpcallback?&jsonpcallback=jQuery1124095…_147537848103…:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

I then looked into `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` and discovered that there is a work around if there is no support on server side for `jsonp` using `PHP`. 
But since, I also own the server, and it is setup using `nodejs` `http` module, I want to find a way to enable `jsonp` support on the server.

I have read [here](http://ilee.co.uk/jsonp-in-express-nodejs/), that it can be enabled on the server when using `express`, as follows, `app.set("jsonp callback", true);`, but since I am not using express, I have no idea how can I enable it on the server side ?

This is the code of my `server.js`,

```
// Setup node http server
var server = http.createServer(
        // Our main server function
        function(request, response)
        {
                // Grab the URL requested by the client and parse any query options
                var url = require('url').parse(request.url, true);
                var pathfile = url.pathname;
      var query = url.query;

                // Test to see if it's a database query
                if (pathfile == '/temperature_query.json'){
         // Test to see if number of observations was specified as url query
         if (query.num_obs){
            var num_obs = parseInt(query.num_obs);
         }
         else{
         // If not specified default to 20. Note use -1 in query string to get all.
            var num_obs = -1;

        if (query.start_date){
            var start_date = query.start_date;
         }
         else{
            var start_date = '1970-01-01T00:00';
         }
         // Send a message to console log
         console.log('Database query request from '+ request.connection.remoteAddress +' for ' + num_obs + ' records from ' + start_date+'.');
         // call selectTemp function to get data from database
         selectTemp(num_obs, start_date, function(data){
            response.writeHead(200, { "Content-type": "application/json" });
                 response.end(JSON.stringify(data), "ascii");
         });
      return;
      }

      // Test to see if it's a request for current temperature
      if (pathfile == '/temperature_now.json'){
            readTemp(function(data){
                              response.writeHead(200, { "Content-type": "application/json" });
                              response.end(JSON.stringify(data), "ascii");
               });
      return;
      }

      // Handler for favicon.ico requests
                if (pathfile == '/favicon.ico'){
                        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/x-icon'});
                        response.end();

                        // Optionally log favicon requests.
                        //console.log('favicon requested');
                        return;
                }


                else {

                else {
                        // Print requested file to terminal
                        console.log('Request from '+ request.connection.remoteAddress +' for: ' + pathfile);

                        // Serve file using node-static
                        staticServer.serve(request, response, function (err, result) {
                                        if (err){
                                                // Log the error
                                                sys.error("Error serving " + request.url + " - " + err.message);

                                                // Respond to the client
                                                response.writeHead(err.status, err.headers);
                                                response.end('Error 404 - file not found');
                                                return;
                                                }
                                        return;
                                        })
                }
});
server.listen(8000);
```

Can someone kindly help me and tell me how can I enable support for the `jsonp` on the node js server without using `express` api ?

Comment: You're going to have to implement it yourself, "plain" `http` doesn't know about JSONP.